# Rails Activerecord: create or update after HTTP POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and Android, so please don't blame me if the question was answered before somewhere, but after searching for an answer I did't find anything.

Question: How do I assure that Rails creates or updates the field IP which should also be unique in the database. I sent a HTTP POST from Android device to "http://192.168.5.3:3000/users/create?user[user_ip]="+myIp+"user[user_name]="+name

So on the Rails' server side, Rails should check if myIp already exists and if so, it should update the "user_name" to "name", and if it won't find myIp, it should create a new record with both fields.

Should I use before_create in the user.rb model? Or how do I do that? Should I use POST or PUT? If I should use PUT, then I don't know the id if the user exists.

Or shouldn't I use the Rails action "create" at all and write a custom Webservice method?

Sorry for such maybe lame question but somehow I can't figure it out!

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use PUT for update and POST for create. If you know the user exists, but you don't have the id, you would use a PUT request, and in the update method, you would have something like this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_ip(params[:ip])
  if @user.update_attributes(...)
    #success
  else
    #failure
  end
end
```

Again, the ideal method would be to pass the id into the update, but if you are unable to do that, you don't want to sacrifice RESTful conventions.

Comment: thanks! but what URL should I call from android as HTTP PUT http://192.168.5.3:3000/users/update?user[ip]="+myIp+"user[user_name]="+name ? (here :id would be missing since rake routes says PUT /users/:id) Or should I add a new route so that the id is not neccessary for the HTTP PUT?

Comment: I want that Rails looks up in the DB for the IP and if it finds the IP it should update it with the name string and if not  it should create a new record with IP and name. So PUT forces me to pass an id like in the routes. What should I do?

Comment: Ok, I think I got you. I just pass any id like 42 - it doesn't matter just for ignoring errors. So http://192.168.5.3:3000/users/42?user[ip]="+myIp + "&user[name]="+name . It works now, but one question in the update method, why can't I say (at)user = User.find_by_ip(params[:ip])  it throws a nil object every time. I have to create a new user to access ip field (at)u = User.new(params[:user]) and then (at)user = User.find_by_ip(@u.ip) . why can't i directly access ip via params[:ip] ?

Comment: You might also want to look into friendly_id (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It will allow you to override the default id params. This is NOT the ideal solution, if you can possibly get the ID out to your app, you would be much better off doing that! Hope this helps!

Comment: You are passing user[ip] as a param. If you want to use params[:ip], you need the params to be ?ip="+myIp"